# How to do we exclude files and folders from Sonarqube analysis using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I am trying to exclude the folder **/target/* and getting the following error:

````
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'xxxxx'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.```
````

Comment: This is what is in my build.gradle file pertaining to Sonarqube:
   
```dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
    }```

Comment: subprojects { dependencies { classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2" } apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'maven-publish' apply plugin: 'jacoco' apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube' group 'xxxxx' version '0.0.1' sourceCompatibility = 1.8 sonarqube { properties { property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "**target/**/*" } }